# SlideUp all divs & change h3 class with one button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, callback, slider, accordion, slideup

I have a simple accordion type mechanism that I've been working on. I am familiar with slideUp and slideDown's callback functionality and have used this to achieve the changing of classes after animations have completed.

I have 2 buttons - one expands all divs in the accordion and the other collapses them. This works fine and when using only those buttons to control the accordion the classes are changed at the correct times.

However, when I open one of the accordions (by clicking on an h3) and then click on the button to collapse all the divs - the class on the h3 immediately changes (and therefore its appearance).

There must be a conflict somewhere. I'm sure my functions are not particularly we written either but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is the jQuery:

```
$('.accordion h3').addClass('closed').next('div').hide();

        $('.accordion h3').click( function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('closed')){
                $(this).removeClass('closed');
                $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).next('div').stop(true,true).slideDown();
            }   else if ($(this).hasClass('open')){
                    $(this).next('div').stop(true,true).slideUp('normal', function() {
                        $(this).prev('h3').removeClass('open');
                        $(this).prev('h3').addClass('closed');
                    });
                }
        });

        $('#expand-all').click( function() {
            if ($('.accordion h3').hasClass('closed')){
                $('.accordion h3').removeClass('closed');
                $('.accordion h3').addClass('open');
        $('.accordion h3').next('div').stop(true,true).slideDown();
            }
            return false;
        });

        $('#collapse-all').click( function() {
            if ($('.accordion h3').hasClass('open')){
        $('.accordion h3').next('div').stop(true,true).slideUp('normal', function(){
                    $('.accordion h3').removeClass('open');
                    $('.accordion h3').addClass('closed');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

The following html is simplified but the basic structure is the same:

```
<a id="expand-all" href="#">Expand all</a>
<a id="collapse-all" href="#">Collapse all</a>

<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Clickable to trigger dropdown</h3>
    <div>This is the hidden content that shows when the h3 is clicked</div>
    <h3>Clickable to trigger dropdown</h3>
    <div>This is the hidden content that shows when the h3 is clicked</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because one of the accordians is already closed, therefore the slideUp is done and this is calling:

```
$('.accordion h3').removeClass('open');
$('.accordion h3').addClass('closed');
```

Rather than doing $('.accordion h3'), you should be changing the one relative, so try:

```
$(this).prev('h3').removeClass('open');
$(this).prev('h3').addClass('closed');
```

In the collapse all slideUp callback.

Comment: Also, here's the code:

$('.accordion h3').next('div').stop(true,true).slideUp('normal', function(){$(this).prev('h3').removeClass('open');       $(this).prev('h3').addClass('closed');
});